# How to match exact words in Python?

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I'm new to python. I have a set of strings in multiple text file. There i will more that 100 files.

## cool.add.odd.inn.txt

```
weather: cool.add.odd.inn

blab: name= hello.add.COPY_HI
blab: name= hello.add.ACCESS_HELLO
blab: name= hello.add.ADD_HI
blab: name= hello.add.WRITE_HI
blab: name= hello.add.WRITE
blab: name= hello.add.COPY
```

## warm.add.minus.txt

```
weather: warm.add.minus

blab: name= hello.add.COPY_HI
blab: name= hello.add.ACCESS_HELLO
blab: name= hello.add.ADD_HI
blab: name= hello.add.WRITE_HI
blab: name= hello.add.WRITE
blab: name= hello.add.COPY
```

i created a list of pattern match

```
total = ['WRITE_HI', 'COPY_HI', 'ADD_HI'] #there will more than 100 key words
```

i want the exact match of the given input list and write to a csv file.
See my coding

```
state1='weather,state'

weather= os.listdir('./data/weather')
for warm in weather:
    file= open('./data/weather' + warm, 'r')
    ins=file.read()

state1+=warm.replace('.txt', '') + ','

for all_1 in total:
    if all_1 in ins:
        state1 += all_1 + '\n'
state1 += '","'
```

The output gives in csv format,  Now with my code i'm getting partial output by string compare. Here its giving match and also the with similar words(example: i want only 'WRITE_HI' and 'COPY_HI' as per my list but it is also giving 'WRITE' and 'COPY' which as similar string match i don't want that. I want only the pattern in the list. I heard that there is more methods for pattern match like regression match etc.. please anyone help me on this issue. Thanks in advance

```
Output:

weather,state 
cool.add.odd.inn,'WRITE_HI'
'WRITE'
'COPY_HI'
'COPY'
'ADD_HI' 

warm.add.minus,'WRITE_HI'
'WRITE'
'COPY_HI'
'COPY'
'ADD_HI'
```

Update: Result Found with following

```
def word_check(ins, total):
    total=total[:]
    found=[]
    for match in re.finditer('\w+', ins):
        if words in total:
        found.append(words)
        total.remove(words)
    return found
```

Answer (score 2):

Since the matches are always at the end of the line, just include the linefeed in your search query's items.

```
total = ['WRITE_HI\n', 'COPY_HI\n', 'ADD_HI\n']
```

Note that this would mean changing `state1 += all_1 + '\n'` to just `state1 += all_1` since the desired linefeed is already present.

Also, manually assembling a CSV file by concatenating content, commas, etc. is not a good idea. Use a library like the `csv` module.

Comment: @DarshanMahalingeGowda - Adding a linefeed to the terms you're looking for has nothing to do with how you put together a CSV file. The former solves the specific problem you're facing, and the latter solves a ton more problems you're sure to face later on due to reinventing a particularly complex wheel.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3- i check your way of approach but not working for me .

Answer (score 2):

Actually it would be easier to use regular expressions to match them

```
import re
pattern1 = r"\w*\.WRITE\_HI"
pattern2 = r"\w*\.COPY\_HI"
pattern3 = r"\w*"\.ADD\_HI"
#then use re.search method to search and match the names
```

this solution will match and using a if and elif case can classify them into different groups and you can do the processing

Comment: @Surya sorry i didnt get you properly, can you please elaborate the solution , as of my understanding  you want me to include this form in read form i.e ins right ? or should i include in total list?

Comment: @DarshanMahalingeGowda yes you must get the input in read method if you dont wish to alter any of the content, and have some lists created, and add the patterns above with a re.search and classify them into different lists, of common names or according to your condition, hope this helps